# How to add column reporting sum of couple of subsequent rows

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, dataset

I have the following dataset

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("congruent", "incongruent"
), class = "factor"), Var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("spoken", "written"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(8L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I would like to add another column reporting sum of coupled subsequent rows. Thus the final result would look like this:

[image]

I have proceeded like this

```
Table = as.data.frame(table(data_1$unimodal,data_1$cong_cond, data_1$presentation_mode)) %>% 
  mutate(Var1 = factor(Var1, levels = c('0', '1'))) 


row = Table %>%  #is.factor(Table$Var1)
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric),
                   ~ .[Var1 == '0'] +  .[Var1 == '1'],
                   .names = "{.col}_sum"))

column = c(rbind(row$Freq_sum,rep(NA, 4)))
Table$column = column
```

But I am looking for the quickest way possible with no scripting separated codes. Here I have used the **dplyr package**, but if you might know possibly suggest some other ways with map(), for loop, and or the method you deem as the best, please just let me know.

Comment: Do you need the NA in the second observation or could it be filled with the same number?

Comment: Well, I would prefer with NAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```r
df$column <- 
  rep(colSums(matrix(df$Freq, 2)), each=2) * c(1, NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with no `NAs` in the dataframe, you can

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Var2, Var3) %>% 
  mutate(column = sum(Freq))

# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   Var2, Var3 [4]
  Var1  Var2        Var3     Freq column
  <fct> <fct>       <fct>   <int>  <int>
1 0     congruent   spoken      8     10
2 1     congruent   spoken      2     10
3 0     incongruent spoken     10     12
4 1     incongruent spoken      2     12
5 0     congruent   written    10     12
6 1     congruent   written     2     12
7 0     incongruent written    10     12
8 1     incongruent written     2     12
```